# Have two C compilers

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code, gcc, clang

I wanted to set up C language on VSCode, and ended up with 2 compilers (clang and gcc) how can I delete one of them ?

P.S: I'm using M2 Mac, had to notice that

I want a solution to my problem, maybe deleting one of these compilers

Comment: Are you sure you actually have two different compilers? AFAIK, the `gcc` command on macOS refers to `clang` anyway. At least it is this way on my machine where I never installed GCC. What does `gcc --version` output?

Comment: Unless you went out of your way to install `gcc` explicitly, it's just a wrapper around `clang` as ForceBru points out. The `gcc` wrapper isn't a compiler, it's a compatibility stub.

Comment: You can have as many C compilers and versions installed as you like. It doesn't make any difference, it just uses a bit more disk space. Just set your PATH so that you run the one you want.

Comment: Many questions here are about how to install (such) compilers. You've already got two. So, IMO, you're ahead of the game. Just follow Mark's advice [and keep both].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases on Mac, /usr/bin/gcc and /usr/bin/clang are the same file (the file in /usr/bin actually is a "tool finding" app that redirects into the Xcode installation, but in the end they wind up being the same file). This is done for convenience because many scripts refer to "gcc". If you pass `--version`, you'll see that it's really clang:

```
$ gcc --version
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode-15.3.0-Release.Candidate.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

If this is what you're seeing, you only have one compiler installed. It just has two names. Since most of this is done with hard-links, it doesn't take any extra disk space besides a few bytes for extra entries in the directory listing.